# Why does the link step fail with badly formed linker commands when installing certain R packages?

Tags: r

I've started noticing an odd error when attempting to install R packages (R 4.0.6, x86_64, Linux) that require compilation of c++ source.   The final link step seems to get **extraneous text in the command**.  E.g. install.packages("IncDTW"), the trace shows:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions\
-Wl,-z,relro -o IncDTW.so GCM.o RcppExports.o dtw2vec.o dtw_dismat.o\
 dtw_disvec.o help_functions.o init.o \
 rundtw.o Start time: Wed Nov 11 14:56:10 2020 -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
g++: error: Start: No such file or directory
g++: error: time:: No such file or directory
g++: error: Wed: No such file or directory
g++: error: Nov: No such file or directory
g++: error: 11: No such file or directory
g++: error: 14:56:10: No such file or directory
g++: error: 2020: No such file or directory
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: IncDTW.so] Error 1
```

(Command line breaks inserted for readability.) Notice the "Start time: ..." inserted in the final command. This appears whether I use install.package function within R or attempt to install with "R" from a bash shell.
Did some odd environment change occur in my system or is this an issue with certain older packages?  Work-around ideas welcome...

Answer (score 1):

For the record, the problem stemmed from the local environment.  A local `.Rprofile` file had a command capable of writing to `stdout`. It seems this output can land at random locations in the command stream used to invoke external compilers etc.--a surprisingly fragile arrangement.  (Moreover, it seems you can have more than one of these hidden .Rprofile files.)